# Preview render selected renderlayer?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

is it possible to preview the selected renderlayer in the viewport?
I have a couple of renderlayers with override materials that I would like to check in the viewport, but it seems previewrender ignores renderlayers and material overrides completely...
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can preview the current selected render layer by enabling Render Layer button located on 3D View header:

[image]

Comment: awesome.... would have helped if my 3D-view window was wide enough to show all these buttons :)

Comment: Yes, or you can drag the header with MMB to see it. :)

Comment: Yes, I know... but if that button was visible by default I could have found it myself. I just didn't think to scroll that bar to look for it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Haha... indeed.